# Show that a group of order $33$ cannot only have elements of order $11$ and $1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solution-verification

> Show that a group of order $33$ cannot only have elements of order $11$ and $1$.

**Attempt:**

Assume $G$ only has elements of order $11$ and that there exists $x \in G$ such that $o(x) = 11$. Because $x^{o(G)} = e$ we have $x^{33} = (x^{11})^3 = e$ and so  $x^{11}$ has order $3$. Contradiction.

Comment: Well, there's certainly an element of order $1\ne 11$, answering the main problem. - But your conclusion ($y^3=e$ implies that $y$ has order $3$) is wrong

Comment: Corrected for the identity. Oops sorry I realize what I did wrong stupid mistake Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every element $g\in G$ of order $11$ generates a subgroup of $G$ of order $11$. Distinct subgroups of order $11$ intersect trivially, so if $n$ is the number of subgroups of $G$ of order $11$ then the number of elements of $G$ is
$$|G|=n\cdot(11-1)+1=1+10n,$$
which cannot equal $33$, so $G$ cannot have only elements of orders $1$ and $11$.

Comment: Can you explain the stated relation please?

Comment: @Quintic Each element of order $11$ generates a subgroup of order $11$. By Lagrange, the intersection of two distinct subgroups of prime order must be $1$. Let the number of subgroups of order $11$ be $n$. Here we count the elements of $G$. From each $n$ subgroups you get $11 - 1 = 10$ elements of order $11$, which are all distinct. In addition we have the identity element. Thus we get $10n + 1$ elements in total, which cannot be $33$ for any $n$.